# What should be used for background tasks instead of foreground service when app is killed?

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

In my app I want to show notification on exact time when the app is working in background or even it is closed. I used AlarmManager and service with BroadcastReceiver to show notification. The latest versions of android doesn't allow to run service in background after app closed and foreground service is consuming battery, slowing down the device etc.. I wonder if I could use something else can work even app is closed and show the notifications. I've heard of WorkManager and JobScheduler for that kind of operations but can they do the work even if app is closed?

Comment: Yeah they do the work even if app is closed .. That what they build for...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 0):

Foreground services is not consuming more battery and not slowing down device, just notification is shown.

And the answer is basically it is not possible to make continuous background service on new android API's. You only can schedule tasks with tools like `WorkManager`, `JobScheduler` and so on.

These days I think `WorkManager` is the answer because Android team is focused on it this year.

Also even continuous foreground services gets killed after some time.... To avoid that 2 things has to be done:

1. Native battery optimization for app should be disabled.
2. Phone manufacturer (another battery optimization) has to be also disabled for specific app.....

I know it is worst user experience, and they throwing away half smart things that phone can do, but life is life :)

Comment: I tried WorkManager, There is no problem when app is open. Unfortunately it doesn't work either when app is closed.